# How to shift an std_logic_vector to the right without truncating the first bits

Tags: vhdl

I want to shift an std_logic_vector to the right by d positions, complete the shifted value by 0 in every shift and **never truncate** the remaining bits. This is a concrete example, a='110001', b=shiftRight(a,3) then b equal to '000110001'. The last bits of a '001' isn't truncated but with srl, it will be truncated. Is there any possible implementation?

Comment: You could show declarations and actual VHDL syntax.

Comment: Your example doesn't show any shift example. Your example shows `b <= "000" & a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is just concatenation, as mentioned.  You can also use an unsigned resize to add bits to the left which might work better if the number of bits to add is a variable or parameter:

```
new_slv <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(my_slv),my_slv'length + more_bits));
```